# Retrofit - android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit 2 to get json and parse it to POJO. My purpose is getting one value of that object.

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta4'
```

My REST client:

```
public interface MyClient {

    @GET("/part1/part2")
    Call<MyItem> getMyItem(@Query("param1") String param1,
                                                 @Query("param2") String param2,
                                                 @Query("param3") String param3);

}
```

[Here](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client) I found great great tool to create service:

```
public class ServiceGenerator {

    public static final String API_BASE_URL = "http://my.api.com";

    private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
            new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient.build()).build();
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
}
```

Then I am creating new service using Service generator class:

```
MyClient api = ServiceGenerator.createService(MyClient.class);
        Call<MyItem> call = api.getMyItem(param1, param2, param3);
        MyItem myItem= null;
        try {
            myItem= call.execute().body();
            Log.d("MyTag", myItem.getValue());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

When I am trying to run this code I am getting this error:

> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>                                                                 at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
>                                                                 at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
>                                                                 at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
>                                                                 at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
>                                                                 at okhttp3.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
>                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:173)
>                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:139)
>                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:81)
>                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:174)
>                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:127)
>                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
>                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
>                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:241)
>                                                                 at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponse(RealCall.java:240)
>                                                                 at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:198)
>                                                                 at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:160)
>                                                                 at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:57)
>                                                                 at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:177)
>                                                                 at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:87)
>                                                                 at uz.cp.ox.data.MyRepository.getMyItem(MyRepository.java:31)
>                                                                 at uz.cp.ox.presenters.MyPresenter.do(MyPresenter.java:30)
>                                                                 at uz.cp.ox.activities.MyActivity.onClick(MyActivity.java:52)
>                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
>                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
>                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
>                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

I thought that Retrofit automatically does the job in the background thread. Or I misunderstood something. What is wrong in this situation and how to solve it?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

> I thought that Retrofit automatically does the job in the background
>   thread.

It does if you use the asynchronous version - `enqueue`.  You're using the synchronous version, which runs on the calling thread.

Call it this way instead:

```
MyClient api = ServiceGenerator.createService(MyClient.class);
Call<MyItem> call = api.getMyItem(param1, param2, param3);
call.enqueue(new Callback<MyItem>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<MyItem> call, Response<MyItem> response) {
        MyItem myItem=response.body();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<MyItem> call, Throwable t) {
        //Handle failure
    }
});
```

In onResponse(), use `response.body()` to get your response, such as:
    `MyItem myItem=response.body();`

Edit: Fixed onResponse() & onFailure() signatures and added example to onRespnose().

Comment: What if I want to call the service synchronously?

Comment: See this code from the OP:  
`Call<MyItem> call = api.getMyItem(param1, param2, param3);  
call.execute().body();`

Use `.execute()` instead of `.enqueue`.

Comment: Ok but when we do that we get `NetworkOnMainThreadException`, can't we make sync. call without having exception?

Comment: Yes @GokhanArik, but to call it synchronously, you need to be on a background thread, such as in an AsyncTask, a job queue or your own background thread.

Comment: For anyone who is confused with ServiceGenerator, it's an interface where you write your requests.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling webservice on main thread, that's why u got this error '**android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException**'.

You can use the above coding answered by [NightSkyDev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1626190/nightskydev) to get the data what u want.

Comment: In Rxjava & Retrofit I forgot to write threads 
              .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
              .observeOn(AppSchedulers.mainThread())
So I get this error. Thanks for answer

Answer (score 3):

In Retrofit Two Types of Method execution takes place-
**Enqueue** - Works on background thread automatically handle by retrofit.
**Execute** - Works on UI thread manually required to put in either background thread or take help of async task.